# How to run a program with python 3.x

Tags: linux, python-3.x, ubuntu-10.10

I use ubuntu 10.10, and I have both Python 2.x and Python 3.x. I have a program that needs to run with python 3.x (blender 2.5x).
How do I run a program with python 3.x?

Comment: Belongs on http://www.superuser.com

Comment: not sure if "through" == "with" in your question.

Comment: @Yasir feels like it but its a programing config-ish question

Comment: @giddy Before editing there were some french words in the question, so I think he's not a native english speaker and had it translated via software.

Comment: @Lordi Lordi: And when it get's migrated to superuser.com, remember to add the error message. Otherwise people have to just guess wildly.

Answer (score 4):

Usually a symlink is created in your path called `python3`.

So you should just need to call your program via

```
python3 ProgramName.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Installation

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

Even after installing python3, python 2.7 will stay and be default

Now, the way to run python3 code->

**Method 1**

Run `python3`
Now write the code

**Method2**

Run a save sample.py file

```
python3 sample.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a separate python executable for python 2.x and for python 3.x?  On my system I have /usr/bin/python2.5 and /usr/bin/python2.6.  I also have a /usr/bin/python2, which is a symbolic link to /usr/bin/python2.6.  I presume that you have a /usr/bin/python3 too.  In which case, you simply run the program using /usr/bin/python3 instead of the more generic /usr/bin/python.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Blender is not run with or through Python at all. It's a native compiled executable and runs directly. It does however *embed* Python and use it as a scripting language. Blender 2.5 uses Python 3, and for this to work you need Python 3 installed on your system in the path, so blender can find it.

That's all, afaik.